# How to find and delete duplicate rows based on shell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have +18k rows and each row represents possible variant of a machine (axle diameters, rotation speeds, materials, calculated stresses and so forth).

The problem is that there is unnecessary duplicates. What I mean is that in some cases for example a shaft can be made of normal steel and thus high tensile steel. In this case the high tensile steel variant is unnecessary, because the normal steel can withstand the stresses and it is cheaper as well. 
I am a mechanical engineer..not a software engineer. That's why I am asking that how to delete those unnecessary combinations?

I am able to determine that is the row duplicate or not with IF and SUMPRODUCT functions.

> =IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$6:$A$18817=A7126)*1;($F$6:$F$18817=F7126)*1;($H$6:$H$18817=H7126)*1;($K$6:$K$18817=K7126)*1;($L$6:$L$18817=L7126)*1;($AK$6:$AK$18817=AK7126)*1)>1;"Duplicates";"No")

And by sorting column by column I can find the rows that are duplicate between each other. Now I am able to delete manually row by row, but there must be a better way to do this.

In the image below, rows 7126, 12434 and 17598 are duplicates, but the material is different. I would like to remove all the others, but not 12434. Hints??

[image]

Comment: Hmmmm.. Somehow eshwar was able to generalize the question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In another sheet add all material codes in one column and the order of priority in the next column. For example, normal steel will have priority 1 and tensile steel will have 2. Then add a column in this sheet to lookup the priority using VLOOKUP.

Then sort this sheet, using priority in descending order so that the most preferred material will come above the lesser preferred material. Then use Excel's Data - Remove duplicates and choose columns A, F, H, K, L, and AH.

It's a good idea to convert the priority column to values by copy and paste-special values. You may also want to keep a backup before starting this task.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds promising. Have to test it.